# deploying a Symfony 4.3 application

Tags: symfony, deployment, symfony4

I am new to Symfony4 and i can't deploy it on my host...

I created a sub domain to test my website before uploading it (http://symfony.photoclubchirac.org/) on my host (nuxit).

I asked them if they already have a tutorial for uploading Symfony on their system but they don't know how to do it, and they asked me to see with a web master..

I upload all my files (i think it's the first step to do) and then i am at the ["Check requirements" step](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#a-check-requirements).
Here i am stuck cause i have to install Composer and Symfony but i don't have any ssh access on my host account...
How can i know if all the technical requirements are ok please ?

*2019-12-03 (11:57)* - **EDIT 1 :**

I also tried to send config, public, src, templates, var, vendors folders and .env file but the website shows me an error (you can see this error on [my website](http://symfony.photoclubchirac.org/))

```
The autoloader expected class "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\Type\FormTypeHttpFoundationExtension" to be defined in file "/web6/photoclubchirac/www/symfony/vendor/composer/../symfony/form/Extension/HttpFoundation/Type/FormTypeHttpFoundationExtension.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

I checked but i have in this file :

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\Type\FormTypeHttpFoundationExtension
```

and the class exists in the file...

Comment: Deploying like this would be hard. Do you have a ssh access at least?

Comment: No i don't have any ssh access..
What is the good thing to do tu upload my website easier ?

Comment: You need a some different things and a ssh access to deploy.                        
Follow the documentation => https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/deployment.html.              Or give us more explainations if you need more help.

Comment: May be try: https://medium.com/@runawaycoin/deploying-symfony-4-application-to-shared-hosting-with-just-ftp-access-e65d2c5e0e3d

Comment: Is ssh needed ? I asked for my host but he sais me that he doesn't offer this option...

Comment: You can always try to upload everything via sftp/ftp , but doing it like that is error prone, because you will never be sure if you have all classes uploaded. 

Have you checked, that you development environment offers the same parameters like the hosting environment?

Comment: @COil Thanks, i will try that and see if it resolve my problem. It seems to be well explained

Comment: @CalamityJane I checked and php has the same version in local and on the hosting environnement, so it seems to be ok

Comment: And please add to your question, the errors you get at the moment. This way viewers of your question can still learn something from it, when you have fixed your problem.

Comment: Checking for the same version is not enough though. You also have to check for enabled libraries.  Run phpinfo() on your dev system and on the host system and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install dependencies via:

`composer install`

> //for development mode

`composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`

> //for production mode

Comment: I can't cause as I said in my first post, _i don't have any ssh access on my host account_

Comment: You can execute this commands locally to prepare your build for production and then upload with ftp all your project. Be careful to NOT upload the var directory on the other hand. Maybe you will have some trouble with the generation of this directory on your server and you will have to set rights manually (for the cache and the logs)

Comment: I tried to but the result is my website shows me an error (i updated my question above)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just upload all the project including the vender folder it will take time for sure but that the only way I can see you bypassing the composer install

Comment: Including the vendor can resolve my problem ?
I will try this and i come back to you when it's done

Comment: you are missing .htaccess file on your server for the Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.